# What is a task lifecycle? when will it end or collected in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task

I'm pretty new in TPL, and I'd like to get an answer to the question :
What is a task lifecycle? when will it end or collected in C#?
If the task is created for a single use - it does its one-time work and then completed - do I need to cancel it?
does the garbage collector collect it?

Here is an example:

```
    DoSomething()
   {
      Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoOneTimeWork());
   }
```

Is there anyone who can tell me what happened to the local task after DoOneTimeWork is ended?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/25/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/ help?

Comment: It's good to sometimes focus in on things but I think your specific area of focus is incorrect here. When and how GC happens is frequently uninteresting and it's usually enough to know that it happens and does "the right thing" without having to worry too much about the details. Here, with this code, I'd be far more concerned about any *unobserved exceptions* arising out of `DoOneTimeWork`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about GC, I'll answer, but as I say I don't think it's particularly interesting and I'd be more concerned about any unobserved exceptions caused by your code, since you neither expose a reference to the task yourself nor queue any further interactions with it via `ContinueWith`.

At the point at which `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns (although `Task.Run` is usually preferred these days), the runtime system will have created a task and will be maintaining a strong reference to that task. Until `DoOneTimeWork` has completed, either normally or abnormally, that reference at least will prevent the `Task` object from being collected.

Once `DoOneTimeWork` has completed, the `Task` will be updated to record its completion status and the runtime will no longer maintain a reference. Since `DoSomething` never reads from `task`, and (as stated above) no other references to the `Task` would appear to be possible, then even if `DoSomething` is still running, the `Task` will now be eligible for collection, at some future point in time<sup>1</sup>.

When that collection will occur is of course not known deterministically. For all we know, your code is running in a custom CLR with the [Zero Garbage Collector](http://tooslowexception.com/zero-garbage-collector-for-net-core/) and so may in fact never be collected.

> do I need to cancel it?

No, cancellation in TPL is *cooperative*. It involves the use of `CancellationToken`s, and once cancellation has been requested, code running *within* the `Task` needs to have access to the cancellation token and to implement some logic to make cancellation occur.

If the specific `Task` has already *completed* then it's not in a position to be running any further code, and so even if your code was using a `CancellationToken` and requested cancellation, it won't end up cancelled and doesn't need to be.

---

<sup>1</sup>Which is just about the same story for any other managed object in the runtime - once all strong references to the object are no longer reachable from GC roots then the object will become eligible for collection<sup>2</sup>. That's why I said I don't think it's particularly interesting.

<sup>2</sup>Or *finalization* and collection, for objects with finalizers, with all the usual caveats around that.

Comment: what if the Task instance is kept as a field, Will it not allow GC?

Comment: So following your logic , there is no way my  task will get collected/stopped by the GC in the middle of execution right , even if the scope of the variable that points to it has ended.